# Modify Ctypes to invoke static libraries for Python

Tags: python, ctypes

Is it possible to modify Ctypes src code to support static libraries for Python (eg. I can modify Ctypes to add some additional funcs to invoke static library)?

Since for special reasons, I have to compile everything into one giant Python blob (including Python interpreter, and user Python .py programs(zip section)). Therefore, I cannot use separate .so libraries during my Python blob running.

BTW: Python C extension is not considered here, since my clients' code uses Ctypes to bridge there C code for Python. I don't want to change too much in their side.